# Problema con instalación de Livewire en producción (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, livewire

Tengo un proyecto en Laravel 8.5 y componentes de Livewire 2.5, instalo con:

```
composer require livewire/livewire
```

En local queda perfecto y funcionan los componentes, el problema viene en producción, la instalación supuestamente termina perfecto, hace la actualización y autoload pero luego con:

```
php artisan list
```

No me muestra nada de Livewire, no existe make:livewire ni todos los comandos livewire:make por ejemplo.

En producción tengo un par de componentes creados hace un tiempo que están funcionando, los había creado en el proyecto local, los copié y andan bien... ahora pruebo creando un nuevo componente en el proyecto local y funciona bien, pero cuando lo paso a producción la ruta me devuelve un error 500...

> Status Code: 500  (from service worker)

Al parecer el problema podría estar relacionado con el service worker pero regenero el sw y sigue dando el mismo error. Pareciera que está sirviendo esa ruta desde el service worker pero no debería porque no la tengo cacheada a esa ruta en particular, sigo revisando, cualquier cosa lo comento.

Agrego aquí las líneas relacionadas de mi composer.json:

```
 "livewire/livewire": "^2.5",

    "extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "providers": [
            "Livewire\\LivewireServiceProvider"
        ],
        "aliases": {
            "Livewire": "Livewire\\Livewire"
        },
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},

    "scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "@php artisan vendor:publish --force --tag=livewire:assets --ansi"
    ],
```

He hecho composer update y está con la última versión de livewire (2.5) pero no me funciona en producción.

He probado modificando en config/livewire.php la variable asset_url con la dirección de la carpeta vendor en el servidor pero tampoco.

Comment: ¿No funciona livewire en absoluto o solo no te aparecen los comandos artisan de livewire?

Comment: Funciona en producción, tengo un par de componentes creados hace un tiempo que están funcionando, los había creado en el proyecto local, los copié y andan bien... ahora pruebo creando un nuevo componente en el proyecto local, funciona bien en local pero cuando lo paso a producción la ruta me devuelve un error 500... es rarísimo. Además, en producción no me aparecen los comandos livewire, lo comenté porque tal vez indica algo pero no sé.

Comment: Deberías poner el mensaje de ese error 500 que mencionas.

Comment: Bien, agregado.

Comment: ok, ahí lo comenté, al parecer el error 500 proviene del service worker pero regenero ese sw con 'npm run generate-sw' y sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: Pareciera que está sirviendo esa ruta desde el service worker y genera el error porque necesita trabajar dinámicamente con los datos, pero no tengo cacheada esa ruta en particular, sigo revisando, cualquier cosa lo comento.

Comment: A medias pero solucionado, lo dejo respondido por si le pasa a alguien más...

Comment: en mi caso actualice el php a 8 y kboom, dejaron de funcionar los componentes livewire, borre el archivo de cache y limpie la cache y nada, alguna sugerencia

Comment: Problema resuelto, el tema esta con el header meta que utilice para adaptar mi pagina automaticamente a cualquier pantalla, y de paso evitar las media queries, en fin a trabajar el css se ha dicho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente he encontrado el problema, la instalación de livewire sigue siendo deficiente porque no dispongo de los comandos php artisan pero al menos he logrado que el sistema me reconozca nuevos componentes livewire.

La carpeta cache dentro de la carpeta bootstrap no está funcionando bien, dentro existe un archivo livewire-components.php con el detalle de componentes creados, cada vez que se crea un nuevo componente este archivo se actualiza automáticamente pero por alguna razón que desconozco en mi servidor en producción no lo hace. He debido reemplazar con el mismo archivo que tengo en local y se solucionó el problema.

Incluso probé borrando pero no lo regenera, es raro, pero bueno, ese era el problema.

Lo dejo respondido por si a alguien más le pasa.

Comment: FabianM muy agradecido por tu aporte me salvo enormemente tu aporte, horas llevaba probando y reconfigurando y nada me funcionaba, actualice dicho archivo y anda una barbaridad gracias infinitas